# GSL thread safety problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, gsl

Does GSL have thread-safety issues when it comes to using function pointers? The attached openmp code integrates f(x)=-(c+x)^{-1} over the range 1<=x<=2 for various values of c using gsl's gsl_integration_qng function. The parallel version runs much slower than the serial version. I suspect that this has to do with the function pointer &fx. Does anyone have prior experience with this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<omp.h>

double fx(double x,void *p);
double evalintegral(double c);

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // numerically integrate the function f(x) = -(c+x)^{-1} between 1 and 2
    int Ncs = atoi(argv[1]);
    int Nreps = atoi(argv[2]);

    printf("Ncs=%d, Nreps=%d.\n",Ncs,Nreps);

    int i, j;
    double tempF;

    double *cs = new double[Ncs];
    double dc = 1 / (double)(Ncs-1);

    for (i = 0; i < Ncs; i++)
    {
        cs[i] = dc*(double)i;
    }

    printf("Began integrations.\n");

#pragma omp parallel for default(none)\
shared(Nreps,Ncs,cs)\
private(i,j,tempF)
    for (i = 0; i < Nreps; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < Ncs; j++)
        {
            tempF = evalintegral(cs[j]);
        }
    }

    delete[] cs;

    printf("Finished integrations.\n");

    return 0;

}

double fx(double x, void *p)
{
    double *c = (double*) p;
    return -1 / (*c + x);
}

double evalintegral(double c)
{
    double *ptr_c = new double[1];
    ptr_c[0] = c;
    gsl_function Fquad;
    Fquad.params = ptr_c;
    Fquad.function = &fx;

    size_t quadneval;
    double quadres, quaderr;

    gsl_integration_qng(&Fquad,1,2,1e-10,1e-6,&quadres,&quaderr,&quadneval);

    delete[] ptr_c;

    return quadres;
}
```

Comment: `cs` is shared and used in the inner loop. Consequently only 1 thread can do work at a time, just with additional synchronization overhead. Could that be it?

Comment: That's not it. I tried the code by setting tempF = evalintegral(0) with the same results

Comment: The [GSL manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Thread_002dsafety.html) claims thread-safety. How do you measure the time?

Comment: Yes, the GSL manual has the following quote: "All the functions are thread-safe, in the sense that they do not use static variables. Memory is always associated with objects and not with functions. For functions which use workspace objects as temporary storage the workspaces should be allocated on a per-thread basis." This is what makes me conjecture that this has something to do with the function pointer. I time the program using cygwin's time command. The opemp code spends significant time in system calls while the serial code does not.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with an GSL integral routine. As @mrx_hk mentioned the problem was **reusing the workspace object**. 
In my case I stored:

```
gsl_integration_workspace * w_ = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1200);
```

as a class member variable and reused the storage on every integration call, which caused a race condition.
The solution was to **create a workspace object for every thread**, in my case for every integration call.